# access a variable from azure pipeline's library variable group in side the built in function 'eq' in a template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to access the variable (defined in pipeline's library variable group) in side an 'if' expression using built in function 'eq' in my template yml file.

MY_VARIABLE_GRP has
**key**: SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD
**Value**: 'sonarqube'

**main.yml**

```
    resources:
      repositories:
        - repository: templates
          type: git
          name: MY_PROJECT/MY_TEMPLATE_REPO
stages:
  - stage: "Build"
    displayName: Build
    variables:
      - group: MY_VARIABLE_GRP
    jobs:
    - template: MODULE1/include-my-template.yml@templates
```

**include-my-template.yml**

```
jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo val: $(SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD) ##IT PRINTS 'sonarqube'
          echo SC: ${{eq(variables['SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD'], 'sonarqube')}} ### Always returns fails  

    - ${{ if eq(variables['SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD'], 'sonarqube') }}:
       - DO THIS..
```

As per ADO docs the 'eq' Converts right parameter to match type of left parameter. Returns False if conversion fails.

Tried all the below options and all prints False:

```
# - task: CmdLine@2
#   inputs:
#     script: |
#       echo val: $(SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD) ## PRINTS 'sonarqube'
#       echo SC: ${{eq(variables['SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD'], 'sonarqube')}}  
#       echo SC: ${{contains(variables['SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD'], 'sonarqube')}} 
#       echo SC: ${{eq('$SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD', 'sonarqube')}}  
#       echo SC: ${{eq('"$SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD"', 'sonarqube')}}
```

Comment: Any suggestions plz

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 1):

Variable groups are a resource that is authorized at job runtime and only available for use in runtime expressions. [This issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/template-expression-syntax-doesnt-work-for-variabl/930908?viewtype=all) have been reported here.

If you want some tasks to be executed only when the variable `SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD` is `sonarqube`. You can use [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) (`condition: eq(variables['SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD'], 'sonarqube')`)as workaround. See below:

```
- powershell: echo "run this task when SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD is sonarqube"
  condition: eq(variables['SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD'], 'sonarqube')
```

Or you can define `SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD` as [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) (Or Variables section) and pass to the template parameters. See below:

```
parameters:
- name: SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD
  type: string
  default: sonarqube
  values:
  - sonarqube
  - sonarcloud

#or define in the variables section
#variables:
#  SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD: sonarqube
```

--

```
jobs:
    - template: MODULE1/include-my-template.yml@templates
      parameters:
       SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD: ${{parameters.SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD}} 
       #define in the variables section
       #SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD: ${{variables.SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD}}
```

--

```
  parameters:
    SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD: ""
    
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo val: $(SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD) ##IT PRINTS 'sonarqube'
          echo SC: ${{eq(parameters.SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD, 'sonarqube')}} ### Always returns fails  

    - ${{ if eq(parameters.SONARQUBE_OR_SONARCLOUD, 'sonarqube') }}:
       - DO THIS..
```